# Trying to understand this assembly code correctly

Tags: c++, assembly, encryption

```
__asm {
    encryptX:  push ecx             //push to manipulate
    xchg eax, ecx                   //exchange values in eax and ecx / eax holds old ecx 
    neg  al                         //divide least bit of eax by negative 1  (old ecx)
    ror  al, 1                      //rotate right least most bit by 1 of eax 
    xor  al, byte ptr[ecx]          //exlcusive or least most bit against ecx value being pointed at
    push edx                        //push edx onto stack for manipulatio
    mov  edx, eax                   //move eax into edx
    xchg eax, ecx                   //swap values of ecx and eax
    rol  byte ptr[eax], 3           //rotate left the byte being pointed at 3 times
    xor  dl, byte ptr[eax]          //xor the least bit by pointed value in eax
    rol  dl, 2                      //rotate left the least bit in edx by 2
    mov  eax, edx                   //move edx value into eax
    pop  edx                        //pop values out
    pop  ecx                        //pop values out
    ret                             //return
}
```

i THINK i am right with most of it just need confirmation with some lines
For instance `xor  al, byte ptr[ecx]` i understand it will xor the least most bit of the eax register but i do not understand by what? byte ptr[ecx] is where i get confused.

Comment: `byte ptr[ecx]` means the byte in memory at the address contained in register `ecx`

Comment: Even though you already get answers you should write down your assembly dialect and assembler you are using. That will ease understanding for future readers (who may be in seek of an answer).

Comment: ok thank you, would you say my other comments are explanative and not just saying the obvious? (bar pop is pop)

Comment: at 'neg al' ecx initially equals 31
after it is divided by -1 it equals CF can someone help me with this?

my understand was al is the least most bit of the eax reg (previously 31 so would equal 3)

how do i get to CF from 31?

Comment: I don't see any division by -1. And what does "divide least bit of eax by negative 1" mean?

Comment: EDIT TO ABOVE POST OUT OF TIME i realise my mistake here im thinking just normal decimal maths
i need to twos complement the 31 but again doesnt al mean eax least most bit? being 1?

Comment: Saying "least significant **bit**" is confusing when you either mean (or should mean) "least significant **byte**"

Comment: what would be the difference between least sig bit and byte? 
is bit the single part of the byte? and byte is the 4 bits per byte?

so when i twos complement 'al' that means manipulate the last 4 values of the appropriate binary value?

Comment: A byte is typically 8 bits.

Comment: Thanks again everyone i think i understand now 

i forget some important things everynow and then!

Comment: You posting this code and not knowing the difference between a bit and a byte scares me somehow. :)

Comment: i was out of the game for a few months still getting those gears back up and going haha